# UITableView doesn't display the cells in IOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, hierarchy

I have this issue when I tried to convert my app from iOS6 to iOS7/iOS8.

[image: UITableView doesn't display the cells (working in iOS6)]

`UITableView` doesn't display the cells (working in iOS6).

I have a similar view that works fine in iOS7 (it doesn't have the `UISearchView`)

[image: Working fine in iOS7]

I tried several workarounds like clear the background, delete the UISearchBar, etc...

The code is similar in both examples (cells are generated by `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`method)

I used the Reveal software to analyze this hierarchy.

The code compiled in the XCODE 4 for iOS6 support is working fine. (tested on the iphone 5s with iOS7)

EDIT:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellAloj";
AlojamentoTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if(cell==nil){
    posicao=0;
}
posicao=70+(100*indexPath.row);
[bdAl.arrayFotos removeAllObjects];    NSMutableString *simbpreco=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
NSNumber *id1=[bdAl.idAlojamento objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self drawviewRank:[id1 integerValue]];
//posicao=posicao+100;

cell.backgroundView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"aloj_cell3.png"]];
//Não aparecer mais celulas depois da última com conteúdo
UIView *footer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.tableView1.tableFooterView = footer;
///////////////
[bdAl SelectFotos:[[bdAl.idAlojamento objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]integerValue]];
cell.nomeAloj.text=[bdAl.arrayNomeAloj objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.imgAloj.image=[[UIImage alloc]init];
UIImage *imagem=[bdAl.arrayFotos objectAtIndex:0];
cell.tipo.text=[bdAl.arrayTipoAloj objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.labelLocalidade.text=[bdAl.arrayLocalidade objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.imgAloj.image=imagem;
CALayer * l = [cell.imgAloj layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:10.0];
cell.detailAloj.text=[bdAl.arrayDescAloj objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
int i=[[bdAl.arraypreco objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]integerValue];
for (int j=0; j<i; j++){
    [simbpreco appendString:@"€"];
}
[tableView1 setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];

[tableView1 setSeparatorColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_menu.png"]]];
cell.preco.text=simbpreco;
return cell;
```

EDIT2:

Storyboard:
[image]

EDIT3: This method returns 17 rows:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [bdAl.arrayNomeAloj count];
}
```

And the numberOfSectionsInTableView method:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```

EDIT4:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AlojamentoTableViewController.h"
@interface AlojamentoTableCell : UITableViewCell{

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tipo;
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *nomeAloj;
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *detailAloj;
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *imgAloj;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelLocalidade;
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *preco;
@end
```

Comment: have you tried turning off autolayout?

Comment: @RezaShirazian yes, same issue.

Comment: Can you paste your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: code?

Comment: @JustinMoser code added. Maybe it's a little confuse.

Comment: The cell is from a NIB? If not, are you definitely building inside `contentView`?

Comment: @Tommy no and yes I'm building inside ContentView.

Comment: @Tommy I added a storyboard image to help to understand the hierarchy.

Comment: Okay but there's something very wrong with your view hierarchy. Those stars and things (DYRateView and so on) - the Reveal hierarchy shows that you are adding them _directly to the table view_. You should not be doing that. You should be adding things to the _cells_. - It is not that it doesn't _display_ the cells; it has no cells at all.

Comment: Yes, I know, the rate system is something I have to improve I did it programmatically so I failed in that point when I added it to the view. Whatever, the same project with the same code work just fine in xcode 4.6/iOS6.

Comment: The fact that the "code works" does not make it right. You must stop doing that.

Comment: Can you show the header/properties for your `AlojamentoTableCell` class?

Comment: .h code added (edit 4)

Comment: @FabioCardoso, I asked for the header for the `AlojamentoTableCell` class, not the `AlojamentoTableViewController` class.

Comment: But we can see that the cells are not getting into the table view. The Reveal.app hierarchy has NO cells in it. So what is happening to them?

Comment: Okay, I have another idea. Do you implement or set `rowHeight` or `heightForRowAtIndexPath`? If this is zero, no cell will get into the table.

Comment: @matt no, I don't have it, can you provide an example please? In iOS6 it was necessary?

Comment: I checked it again on the storyboard I had rowHeight 100 custom.

Comment: @matt I think the problem is my `UISearchBar`. What is the difference between `UISearchBar` hierarchy in iOS6 and iOS7/8? I have this problem in 2 UITableView's of my app, the only one that works is which doesn't have the `UISearchBar`.

Comment: There's no search bar in the Reveal analysis of your view hierarchy....

Comment: I think it's because I have it programmatically, not in the storyboard. I'm sure I have it, and it's working (I can see load the right number of stars when I try to search), maybe the problem is that I have something over the tableview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure it out the problem:

I had this method:

```
-(void)RemoveAllObjects{
    [bdAl.arrayLocalidade removeAllObjects];
    [bdAl.idAlojamento removeAllObjects];
    [bdAl.arrayDescAloj removeAllObjects];
    [bdAl.arrayFotos removeAllObjects];
    [bdAl.arrayMail removeAllObjects];
    [bdAl.arrayTipoAloj removeAllObjects];
    [bdAl.arrayMorAloj removeAllObjects];
    [bdAl.arrayNomeAloj removeAllObjects];
    [bdAl.arrayStar removeAllObjects];
    [bdAl.arrayTelf removeAllObjects];
    [bdAl.arraypreco removeAllObjects];
    NSArray *subviews = [self.tableView1 subviews];
    for (int i=0; i<[subviews count]; i++)
    {
       [[subviews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
    }
    //posicao=90;
}
```

to clear all the content when the user begins to use the Search Feature. This method was called in ViewWillAppear.

I remove it and all things are working right.

Thank you all(I have to review all my code, I know.)

EDIT: The UISerachView hiearchy changed in iOS7 that's why the subviews count failed.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that there is something wrong with your constraints. Views are getting moved/resized and that is causing some parts not to show properly. Other parts show because the views that are being resized are not clipping and so bits you draw yourself are getting placed outside of the view they should be in.

Use the following code to add a border around different views to see where they are. I suspect that you will find that many of them aren't being placed where you think they are.

Another thing to try is to turn off autolayout in your storyboard.

```
@interface UIView (Extension)

- (void)addBorder;
@end


@implementation UIView (Extension)

- (void)addBorder
{
    [self.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
    [self.layer setBorderWidth: 2];
}

@end
```

- EDIT -

Just before this line `cell.nomeAloj.text=[bdAl.arrayNomeAloj objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` add the line `assert(cell.nomeAloj);` and tell me what happens when you run the code.

Comment: When you added a border to the (for example) `cell.nomeAloj` label? Does it show up? Also, put this code in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method `assert(cell.nomeAloj);`

Comment: I added it, nothing happened.

Comment: If the assert didn't fire, and the border didn't show up, then the `nomeAloj` label either has a size of zero or is not on the screen. You need to find out where it went and how big it is. Use `NSLog(@"%@", cell.nomeAloj);` and tell me what it outputs.

Comment: `<UILabel: 0x796db2e0; frame = (112 7; 151 25); text = 'Label'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x796db3a0>>` 5 times, but I have 17 values in the DB.

Comment: It would only show up five times because it only builds the cells that are visible. Try adding this line `cell.nomeAloj.clipsToBounds = NO` and see if it's text shows up somewhere in the cell.

Comment: I added it, I can't see any text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63529/discussion-between-daniel-t-and-fabio-cardoso).

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called that means there should be cells generated. One thing I can think of is that your `UITableView` or `UIView` actually has no size.

So a normal `UITableView` should be able scroll. Are you able to scroll? or even interact with that table?

Comment: Yes I can scroll it and I can see 17 label text's added (the number of objects that generates the number of cells) That label text is in the other method that is call inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
}
```

Comment: Like I said, it's not the background color.